# Using My Self Google Drive Api Without Oauth

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive Api for my Python/Flask App. This app is analyzing the picture and hiding the pictures it will analyze on google drive. The pictures already exist on my own google account.

I am using Oauth2 to access these images. But since I already have my own drive account, Oauth2 is pretty useless.

How do I get to drive outside Oauth2?

Comment: Your application needs to be granted permissions to act on your behalf. Google does not know that whatever code you are running is allowed to access your Google Drive account. What if that code was maliciously executed by a hacker on your machine?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please familiarize yourself with [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) before judging the quality of the protocol.

You have to use OAuth2 with the Google Drive API in order to give permission to your application to perform actions on your behalf.

Think of OAuth2 as a "log-in" mechanism for your application into Google's products, like Drive.

Also, familiarize yourself with the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) to understand how to do this.

Comment: Oauth2 is quite good for third parties. I'm not disparaging it. 
I just want my "own" application to do it myself without oauth2. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by this? You want to do [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#webserver) without a library? Why?